# Visual Studio 2015 Community RC Cordova Javascript Project build error with Orientation=Portrait

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Problem description:

With Visual Studio 2015 Community RC installed, create a new blank cordova javascript project and build it, it's ok.

Now, open config.xml and in the "Common" tag, change the "Orientation" from "Landscape or Portrait (Default)" to "Portrait" and build it.

The error is: Command failed with exit code 8

Comment: I just found you asked the same question in MSDN forum. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/60a57e4d-2eed-4c6d-8e16-be7d26f19b9a/visual-studio-2015-community-rc-cordova-javascript-project-build-error-with-orientation-portrait?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova . Thanks for sharing a workaround there. But it's definitely a tool issue. I am currently confirming with VS tools for cordova team to see if it is known issue.

Comment: A bug has already been opened for this issue. Users need to manually modify the config.xml in code view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I finally figured out the work around myself, after changing it to Portrait, I open the config.xml in code view and change Portrait to portrait and it is OK now.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. Same issue occurred for me when i try to configure to Landscape using  config window in VS 2015 RC.  I opened the config.xml in code view and change Landscape to landscape. It is working now.  When we change using the config window, it is adding the configuration as `<preference name="Orientation" value="Landscape" />` .   But it shoud be "landscape".